# Geoserver WPS clip and ship on Layer group?

Tags: geoserver, wps

Is it possible in geoserver to clip on a layer group rather then a single layer. I have the scenario where i would like to enable the user to extract vector data as zip but not from only a single layer but combination of layers. At the moment the Clip WPS function only accepts a single layer as input. What could the possible solutions for this?

like combining all zip files into a single zip file or using sub processes?

Comment: One solution would be to enhance the clip process to accept one or several layers as an input but you would need to be a java programmer or hire someone who is for that.

Answer (score 2):

MassGIS's OLIVER application has a tool just for this purpose. All the code (Open Layers/ Geoserver) is freely available. Oddly, the tool icon is behind "Available Data Layers", so you have to shrink or close that box to see it. I'm not familiar with the details.